# multiple inheritance - virtual modifier

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, multiple-inheritance

In the common diamond scenario:

```
class MBase {
  public:
    MBase(int) {}
    virtual char const* vf() const = 0;
    virtual ~MBase() {}
};

class D1 : public MBase { //NOT VIRTUAL!!!
  public:
    D1() : MBase(1) {}
    char const* vf() const { return "D1"; }
};

class D2 : virtual public MBase {
  public:
    D2() : MBase(2) {}
    char const* vf() const { return "D2"; }
};

class Bottom : public D1, public D2 {
  public:
    char const* vf() const { return "Bottom"; }
}
```

What would change if I modified the inheritance modifier of Bottom to be virtual for both D1 and D2? I mean, would that make any impact:

```
class Bottom : public virtual D1, public virtual D2 {
  public:
    char const* vf() const { return "Bottom"; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it doesn't. Each class chooses which of its direct base classes may be shared with others. Since `Bottom` is a leaf in your implementation and it has in both cases only one instance of `D1` and `D2`, it will in both cases have exactly one nested object of these types. Since `D1` refuses to share an `MBase`, `Bottom` will have two `MBase` objects nested in it as well.

However `MBase` is not *directly* accessible from both versions of `Bottom` since it is ambiguous. You would have to explicitly cast to `D1` or `D2` in order to access `MBase` through `Bottom` objects (precisely because there are two `MBase`s).

---

The difference would be if you had one `D1` that virtually inherits from `MBase` and one that doesn't.

Comment: OK, so I guess if I had a couple Bottoms, all inheriting virtually from D1 and D2,THEN the leaf would have only one copy of D1 and D2 in all of them... Thanks very much for a perfect answer !